# I want to create a generator which generates the intersection of any two input generators

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I have one generator which generates prime numbers and another one which generates fibbonacci, I want to create a generator which generates the intersection of the above generators or any two input generators in general.

```
def primes():
    yield 2
    i = 3
    while True:
        if is_prime(i):
            yield i
        i += 2
def is_prime(num):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            count = 1
    if count == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def fibonacci_numbers():
    yield 1
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while True:
        c = a+b
        yield c
        a = b
        b = c
```

Comment: Where are these generators? We need to see them first.

Comment: You can use set intersection: `set(fibonacci_numbers()).intersection(set(primes()))`.

Comment: @MrGeek, except your computer will die.... as you can't exhaust Fibonacci / prime..

Comment: @jpp I also forgot to mention that the generators should have an upper limit, fibonacci_numbers(n) and primes(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generator which generates infinite sequence of numbers that are common in primes() and fibonacci_numbers() is :

```
def common(pgen, fgen):
p = next(pgen)
f = next(fgen)
while True:
    if p == f:
        yield p
        f = next(fgen)
        p = next(pgen)
    elif p > f:
        f = next(fgen)
    elif f > p:
        p = next(pgen)

def test():
cgen = common(primes(), fibonacci_numbers())
assert 2 == next(cgen)
assert 3 == next(cgen)
assert 5 == next(cgen)
assert 13 == next(cgen)
assert 89 == next(cgen)
assert 233 == next(cgen)
```